# 10x1 transparent background image repeat-x for what reason?

Tags: css, transparent

I am so curious why this page uses a 10x1 image as repeat-x background. See .intro-frame class div.

http://www.psd2html.com/templates/psd2html/examples/markup/rightbanners/index.htm

```
<div class="intro-frame">

.intro-frame {
background: url("../images/separator-04.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 1px 0 0;
position: relative;
}
```

separator-04.png is 10x1 transparent png image. I checked it. I dont't see the purpuse of using such image here. Anyone knows?

Comment: This question can't be answered objectively (we can only offer suggestion and opinion) unless the site-owner/designer stops by and posts an answer. As such, I'm voting to close as 'not constructive.' Though it's worth noting that I think 'too localized' and 'off-topic' are both equally valid.

Comment: Why not give the chance for other to try. Nothing is objective before there is no answer.

Comment: Because if there's no 'objective' answer, the question [should not be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: As long as someone is wanting to learn something, there is a place for them at SO. That is what this site is for. If you don't like the question, don't answer. But you shouldn't hinder him from picking another person's brain.

Comment: @Jusfeel, it is also a good practice to accept answers if at all possible.

Comment: @SamStar, How? By answering "Was this post useful to you?" ?

Comment: @Jusfeel, You should see a check mark beside the answer, underneath the vote ticker. By clicking it, you accept the answer as the best/most helpful/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a known Internet Explorer transparency bug. See: [IE 8 specific background-image bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128691/ie-8-specific-background-image-bug)

A very strange case where a repeated/tiled background-image smaller than 1x10 would not render. Making the background-image size 1x10 (or greater) causes the issue to go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also I guess the separator PNG image is not 100% transparent or it's useless. Such background style requires more work but seems bringing enough flexibility for future changes as I see it now.